# #[should_panic] doesn't accept constant as expected panic message

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-macros

When running rust unit tests it is very useful to utilize the attribute macro #[should_panic(expect = )] to assert that the test is panicking with the correct error message (which means it's panicking at the line you want it to panic and not because of a different error.

However, in applications that use standardized error messages defined in an errors.rs file, it is not possible to pass the constant for the error message as the argument for expect.

This:

```
pub const ERR_001: &str = "ERR_001 message";

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = ERR_001)]
fn test_function() {

        //test code here

}
```

yields the following error:

```
error: expected unsuffixed literal or identifier, found `ERR_001`
  --> staking/src/storage.rs:74:31
   |
74 |     #[should_panic(expected = ERR_001)]
   |
```

Is there a way to pass a constant or variable to the #[should_panic(expected = )] macro? Or is it necessary to always write message instead of ?

Comment: I think this should be a bug report or feature request on https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues

Comment: @Sprite A feature request; I am not sure whether an RFC is needed here or just FCP.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the rust edition, `panic` doesn't always format the string. In rust 2018 and 2015 editions:

```rust
panic!("problem: {reason}")
```

returns literally

```
"problem: {reason}"
```

Could be that panic isn't formatting correctly?

[source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html#editions)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).